# Assembly Intel 0x80 vs 80h

Tags: assembly

I have seen both

```
int 0x80
```

and

```
int 80h
```

used in Intel's assembly syntax.  Is there any difference between the 2, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Different assemblers have different ways of distinguishing hexadecimal constants from decimal constants. The first example uses a method taken from the C programming language. The second examples uses MASM's method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are equivalent. The difference is they are used among different assemblers.

Note that the `h` postfix leaves the possibility of some misconception about integer constants to the assembler: `FFh` might be considered **either** a constant **or** a **label**. Prepending a `0` character resolves this ambiguity.

Comment: at&t vs intel has nothing to do with this. GNU `as` for example doesn't use `80h` in either mode, and nasm accepts both.

Comment: @Jester Oops, I always thought that, just checked and you seem to be right, thanks for clearing me/that up. Edit on its way.

Comment: Also '80h' is 'old Intel' form, when Motorola used '$80'-form. Nowadays the form '0x80' (probably from C) is most often used.